# VS 2012 SQLite version 3.8.3 update error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

[image]I have just updated my VS 2012 SQLite version to 3.8.3 and now my project is not running and it gives below error:

```
Error   14  The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\ExtensionSDKs\SQLite.WP80\3.8.2\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\SQLite.WP80.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. C:\Users\AbdulRahman\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\sqlite-net-wp8-master\Sqlite.vcxproj 59  5   wQuran
```

I don't know what happend? do I need to rollback this update.

When adding the project, I get below error.

Comment: I'm guessing it is because your vcxproj-file still references the 3.8.2 files (look at the path where it says it can't find it). Open your vcxproj-file in Notepad (or other editor) and update the path to 3.8.3 and see if it helps.

Comment: I have checked it its not sqlite 3.8.2, but its 3.8.3 located in (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\ExtensionSDKs\SQLite.WP80\3.8.3)

Comment: Thanks Karl, solved it by changing the reference.